# modules in subfolders with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, browserify

I created a new app with **[blendid](https://github.com/vigetlabs/blendid)**, a *delicious blend of gulp tasks combined into a configurable asset pipeline and static site builder*

html

```
 <h1 data-module="hoverEnlarge">{{ message }}</h1>
```

js structure

```
app.js
|_____ modules
      |_______index.js
      |_______hoverEnlarge.js
```

js - app.js

```
import './modules'
console.log(`app.js has loaded!`)
```

js - modules/index.js

```
/*
  Automatically instantiates modules based on data-attributes
  specifying module file-names.
*/

const moduleElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-module]')

for (var i = 0; i < moduleElements.length; i++) {
  const el = moduleElements[i]
  const name = el.getAttribute('data-module')
  const Module = require(`./${name}`).default
  new Module(el)
}

/*
  Usage:
  ======

  html
  ----
  <button data-module="disappear">disappear!</button>

  js
  --
  // modules/disappear.js
  export default class Disappear {
    constructor(el) {
      el.style.display = 'none'
    }
  }
*/
```

js - modules/hoverEnlarge.js

```
import anime from 'animejs';

export default class hoverEnlarge {
  constructor(el) {
    var buttonEl = el;

function animateButton(scale, duration, elasticity) {
  anime.remove(buttonEl);
  anime({
    targets: buttonEl,
    scale: scale,
    duration: duration,
    elasticity: elasticity
  });
}

function enterButton() { animateButton(1.2, 800, 400) };
function leaveButton() { animateButton(1.0, 600, 300) };

buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', enterButton, false);
buttonEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', leaveButton, false);
    console.log(el.textContent, '- Enlarge hover effect')
  }
}
```

**THIS WORKS.** As well explained, h1 data-module="hoverEnlarge" refers to its module.

**hoverEnlarge** is an hover effect. I want to create js folders with effects to include in future projects, just cloning this repository. So, we have hoverEnlarge.js, hoverReduce.js, hoverSelect.js and so on.

What is the problem? **Subfolders doesn't work**. If I want a structure like this:

```
app.js
|_____ modules/
      |_______index.js
      |_______hoverEffects/
      |        |_______hoverEnlarge.js
      |        |_______hoverReduce.js
      |        |_______hoverSelect.js
      |________otherEffectsFolder/
               |________effect1.js
               |________effect2.js
```

If I try to put hoverEnlarge here: js/modules/hover/hoverEnlarge.js it doens't work and I get this error

```
ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crystal/src/javascripts/animejs/index.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crystal/src/javascripts/animejs/index.js'
 @ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crystal/src/javascripts/modules/hover/hoverEnlarge.js 3:0-28
 @ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crystal/src/javascripts/modules ^\.\/.*$
 @ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crystal/src/javascripts/modules/index.js
 @ /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crystal/src/javascripts/app.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&noInfo=false&quiet=true&react=false ./app.js
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Just put the full path in data-module

```
<h1 data-module="path/to/file">{{ message }}</h1>
```